# Embed YouTube video within Android webview with autoPlay

Tags: java, android, youtube

Trying to Play embedded  `youtube` video withing `Android WebView` with `autoplay` function using following code snippet

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    mWebview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

    final String mimeType = "text/html";
    final String encoding = "UTF-8";
    String html = getHTML();
    mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    });
    mWebview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
}

public String getHTML() {
    String html = "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" style=\"border: 0; width: 100%; height: 95%; padding:0px; margin:0px\" id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" src=url"

            + "?fs=0\" frameborder=\"0\">\n"
            + "</iframe>\n";
    return html;
}
```

In manifest.I have include following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

In application Tag Used following

```
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

but not worked for me .
what is wrong in it?
Any other Good solution?

embedded `youtube` video not showing within page

Comment: Do you have more detail about the error than "It didn't work?"

Comment: no error.I cant see youtube panel using this code in my webview

Comment: @DavidManheim no error,html page loaded,but embeded youtube portion not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I develop an part of an application using Youtube. Unfortunately, I didn't manage to open Youtube Video with autoplay by loading them in a WebView.

Just open it in the Youtube application and when the user will press the back key, it will return to yours.

Comment: Actually,  as an android user,  I think the behavior that occurs is that it returns you to the youtube home page when you press back.

Comment: I test it this morning in my application and the back key goes back to the app. But if you are talking about the back button in the action bar, the user will stay in the YouTube app.